# SSIS Error: Update Records with stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-update

I have a SSIS workflow where I fill a SQL Server table (260 data rows). In this SSIS workflow I have also implemented a lookup that checks whether the original row has changed. If so it should update it in the SQL Server table via a stored procedure.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_MC_Countries] 
    @alphacode3char NVARCHAR(10),
    @alphacode NVARCHAR(10),
    @numcode NVARCHAR(10),
    @german NVARCHAR(150),
    @english NVARCHAR(150),
    @region NVARCHAR(10),
    @qmr NVARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE [dbo].[MasterData_EDL_MC_Countries]
    SET [alphacode3char] = @alphacode3char,
        [alphacode] = @alphacode,
        [numcode] = @numcode,
        [german] = @german,
        [english] = @english,
        [region] = @region,
        [qmr] = @qmr
```

I get this error:

> An OLE DB record is available.
> Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
> Hresult: 0x80040E2F
> Description: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_MasterData_EDL_MC_Countries'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.MasterData_EDL_MC_Countries'. The duplicate key value is (DEU).".

Why does the code want to **insert** this row instead of **updating** it?

I don't get it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: and you really don't have WHERE-condition in your update-statement ?

Comment: no where clause will update every row to the same thing

Comment: thanks both. The where clause was missing!

Comment: This name `@alphacode3char` contradicts the datatype `NVARCHAR(10)`. Your code should never lie or mislead.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell without seeing the dataset being updated, but perhaps you are updating a row with  when there is already a row with  as its primary key? I would question why you would be updating a unique key also, this would be a PK conflict. Could you show the Table Definition?

Comment: Hi @Mike, the where clause was missing in my stored procedure.
Your hint why updating a unique key is helpful. In my case the key will never be updated as a new key would already have been inserted with a prior lookup. But anyway I have deleted the primary key from the update statement as it is redundant!
Thank you!

Comment: @Stelios yes, it was unclear in your question if the SQL  you displayed was the whole query. Glad you got it sorted.